# Diophantine just with a recurring solution $XY=a^2(ab+1)=K$ (without calculating all K divisors)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, diophantine-equations

I am trying to get a recurring solutions for this kind of Diophantine equation:
$XY=a^2(ab+1)=K$; where $a,b \in$ $\Bbb N$ and $a=even$

First of all, I am industrial engineer, sorry for that :) and if I am trying to do something Math. impossible

I tried it with Alpertron method but I become an identity type like $X_{n+1}=X_n$ https://www.alpertron.com.ar/METHODS.HTM#SolGral

I also had a look to this Question but I could not guess help for me
[Proof that $x^2 - 2y^2 = -1$ has a recurring solution for $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618355/proof-that-x2-2y2-1-has-a-recurring-solution-for-x?rq=1)

**QUESTION**: can somebody help me with a clue to get a recurring solutions without finding all divisors of K?
$\implies$ I suppose that it means not to make calculations to find $(ab+1)$ divisor ones

Ex: for $a=6$ and $b=8$, K=1764. There are 27 $\in\Bbb N$ solutions ¿are the 26+1 predictable with a general recurring formula, just knowing in advance 1 solution of them?

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of divisors of $a^2(ab+1)$ for constant $a,b$? If so, at the very least, $\gcd(a^2,ab+1)=1$ which lets us use the multiplicativity of the divisor counting function, $\tau(a^2(ab+1))=\tau(a^2)\tau(ab+1)$.